# How to integrate mixpanel-ruby with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mixpanel

I'm working on integrating `mixpanel-ruby` with Devise. I have a beginner question, in which function should I include the tracking logic?

For example, for tracking successful log in, should I overwrite `SessionsController#create` or `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`?

If overwriting create, should I insert the code within the `create` function or somehow take advantage of the `block`?

```
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    <<< insert mixpanel tracking code >>>
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

Any of the approaches you proposed could work. Which method is best is a matter of opinion and largely dependent on the preferences of you and your team. The required arguments for your tracking code may also dictate that one method is more preferable than another.

That said, here's what I think:

- I wouldn't recommend overwriting `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`. I'd consider adding mixpanel tracking on top of a method you expect to return a url to be somewhat of a [side effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming), something I like to avoid.
- Slightly better to me would be overriding `SessionsController#create` since I find it less surprising to add tracking behavior here. This could be some variation of:

  ```
  class YourController < Devise::SessionsController
    def create
      super
      track_sign_in(this.resource) if signed_in?
    end

    # or taking advantage of the block
    def create
      super do |resource|
        track_sign_in(resource) if signed_in?
      end
    end

    private
    def track_sign_in(resource)
      # yada yada
    end
  end
  ```
- Overall, I'd prefer to use a filter since I'd consider this a more natural way of adding tangential behavior on top of controller actions.

  ```
  class YourController < Devise::SessionsController
    # or after_action in Rails 4+
    after_filter :track_sign_in 
  end
  ```

Any solution involves overriding some aspect of what Devise provides so the differences among the options are pretty trivial in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Warden's after_set_user hook. The docs state:

> A callback hook set to run every time after a user is set. This
>   callback is triggered the first time one of those three events happens
>   during a request: :authentication, :fetch (from session) and :set_user
>   (when manually set). You can supply as many hooks as you like, and
>   they will be run in order of declaration.

Here's how this could work. Notice the check on the event:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |record, warden, options|
  if options[:event] == :authentication
    # Do authentication things
  end
end
```

More info here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Hooks:after_set_user